# In Woocommerce, how to use a legacy API instead of the latest version?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

In Woocommerce, how to use a legacy API version within another plugin code ?

Currently, the newest API version of Woocommerce is loaded, thus when using WC_API_Server, it uses the latest one, and not a legacy one (version **3** needed) :

```
calling the class LMB_API_Server extends WC_API_Server
```

I cannot change the Woocommerce plugin, nor its version - ideally, all I should be able to do is within the third party plugin that I develop.

In the woocommerce folder :

```
includes\
 api\
  *manyPHPfileofcurrentVersion*
  ...
  legacy\
   v1\ 
   v2\ 
   v3\
     *oldPHPfilesOfAPInneded*
```

*Note* : Woocommerce is a plugin for wordpress - and the API is inside this plugin. (even if the latest API uses wordpress' API itself)

*Update* : Unlike usual, here we need to use the API from the wordpress instance perspective - we would like to extend some of woocomerce methods located in the API. We therefore **do not want to *consume* the API, but to *provide* an extended one.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register an autoloader, [function.spl-autoload-register.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which library you are using... [using the PHP wrapper](https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php)
you set the API version in the configure parameters when initializing the REST API client:

```
$woocommerce = new Client(
  'http://example.com', 
  'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
  'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  [
    'wp_api' => true,
    'version' => 'wc/v1',   <====== SET YOUR WC REST API VERSION HERE
  ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It seems that you are reffering to the API from a client perspective. Is it correct ? We need here to choose the API version from the API provider perspective (to extend the api of the woocommerce plugin) - the information about the folder structure was to specify that. See the "update" that makes it clearer.